# Is there an adjective meaning "having membership in two social classes?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Just as we say "bilingual," "bicultural," etc, is there an adjective to describe someone who belongs to two soical classes? Think, for instance, a successful bourgeois who has now become just as much part of the upper class as he/she is of the middle-class. Thank you.

Comment: It hardly fits the sense I have in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure that the condition is possible. If a person changes social class, the pressures they experience change. One could perhaps attempt to 'feel' the former pressures (eg not being able to go to the Diogenes Club), but one would _know_ that the constraints had changed.

Comment: @assef "parvenu"? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/parvenu

Comment: @Elian I'd say that that's rather someone in transition or someone who's lost contact with society (or both). Neither M nor U, say.

Comment: @Elian "parvenu" is very good word, but it reminds me of an "arriviste". What I am looking for is the act of "straddling" a social boundary such that the person would be a member of both sides of the same fence.  Maybe Edwin Ashworth is right, but I'll hope for more answers/comments. Than you both.

Comment: It was "skitsofrantic"

Comment: @asef How do you like "social straddler," Asef? https://books.google.fr/books?id=q5xy6zPI1gkC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22social+straddler%22&source=bl&ots=iVFdbxTJes&sig=oEEqhWkM3b-FBYnNJP6H6mET_zQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI6Y2jhNSFyQIVxlcUCh0D4Ald#v=onepage&q=%22social%20straddler%22&f=false

Comment: @Elian: Excellent. I thought about it but it is a noun phrase, not an adjectival phrase. Does socially-straddling + [noun] sound like a mouthful to you?

Comment: @Elian: Also I found an academic article entitled "The Bi-Social Oscar Wilde and "Modern" Women". I *think* this coinage may work, but I have to take a glance at its argument. http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1525/ncl.2001.55.4.515?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @asef "socially astraddle" or "socially astride" would sound better to my ears. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/astraddle

Comment: Oh! Thank you actually! Those I did not think of.

Comment: Nouveau riche comes to mind. However, I hasten to add that all such terms are bound to be derisive. Social mobility is resented on all levels. Most people expect others to stay put, and get resentful when they don't.

Comment: @Ricky I don't think that people care one way or the other if others stay put or move around constantly. What is incendiary is if they try to move into _my_ group or move away.

Comment: @Elian You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is certainly possible if we accept that different criteria are used to determine membership in each class. Consider impoverished aristocrats during the Revolution and Napoleonic era. While they were certainly recognized as nobility, they were poor as well. It was an interesting condition for many since having no money they were reduced to living very simply, but still retained a varying degree of influence. The influence often depended on the odds of a Bourbon restoration, but it was real influence that a person without the designator of nobility could not be said to have even with an equivalent, or even greater, fortune. What you would call that I don't know, but somebody from the era must have commented on it, and may have coined a term for it.